# Additive blending for UIKit?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uikit, quartz-2d, metal

We're looking for a way to have UIKit elements (UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView, etc) blend onto the background via additive blending instead of alpha blending. As far as we can tell, there are some hacky ways to do this via CABackdropLayer, but those require private API calls. Additionally one can use CGBlendMode with CGImages to do this, but this requires access to the frame buffer as a CGImage which is also problematic. What is the fastest and cleanest way to have UIKit render onto the framebuffer via additive blending? Is this even possible?